# How to return a number surrounded with parenthesis as a negative number

Tags: select, functions, plpgsql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 integer, col2 character varying(20));
```

Col2 contains numeric value but the negative values corresponds with parenthesis not and minus (-). This is the sole purpose having col2 as character so that we can save negatives with parenthesis.

```
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (100, '12345.50');
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (101, '10000.50');
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (102, '10050.00');
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (103, '(10050.00)');
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (104, '(10000.50)');
```

Now when I display I want the positive numbers to display as normal and the value with parenthesis represent leading minus (-).

```
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1;
100 12345.50
101 10000.50
102 10050.00"
103 (10050.00)
104 (10000.50)
```

I need to present as below

```
100 12345.50
101 10000.50
102 10050.00
103 -10050.00
104 -10000.50
```

Does pgsql have any inbuilt function to handle this?

Thank you, Regards, Shaamil.

Comment: This indeed is a common way to _represent_ negative numbers in accounting systems, but that's no reason to _store_ them this way.

Comment: @mustaccio , thanks for your response , It was challenging to pull data from source with minus for negative values and it would only extract in this format. if we are to pull data from source using copy any way we could achieve for a numeric(12,2) type.

Comment: What do you want to return on errant input like `((1.0)` or `1.0)`?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you define `col2` as `numeric(15,2)` rather than as `character varying`. It is always better to use the appropriate types.

Convert the values on insert:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES
   (104, CAST(translate('(10000.50)', '()', '-') AS numeric(15,2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know of any function for that case,

use a double REPLACE

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 integer, col2 character varying(20));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (100, '12345.50');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (101, '10000.50');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (102, '10050.00');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (103, '(10050.00)');
> ```

> 

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (104, '(10000.50)');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT col1, REPLACE(REPLACE(col2,')',''),'(','-') FROM tab1;
> ```
>
> ```
> COL1 | REPLACE(REPLACE(COL2,')',''),'(','-')
> ---: | :------------------------------------
>  100 | 12345.50                             
>  101 | 10000.50                             
>  102 | 10050.00                             
>  103 | -10050.00                            
>  104 | -10000.50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f72785f830638aa4fc8561684ffce33a)*

Answer (score 0):

> Col2 contains numeric value but the negative values corresponds with parenthesis not and minus (-).

That's a *Character Encoding* of a negative number.
It's *not* what the Database will work with as a negative number.

**Always** store data in the correct Data Type.
Anything else just slows down your queries and weakens the integrity of your data.

> This is the sole purpose having col2 as character so that we can save negatives with parenthesis.

That is an issue for the client [application] that consumes, formats and *displays* the data.